# Select element returning value only when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a select box as follows:

```
<select id="selectbox" class='info-entry-select' name="country"> 
    <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option> 
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

This select box is in a hidden div that, when appearing, refreshes the select box options using ajax and a separate php file. Here's the javascript that updates the select box:

```
$("#changeselectoptions").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "includes/selectoptions.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            // Replace options of select box
            var $el = $("#selectbox");
            var newOptions = result['catsOrderList'];
            // newOptions correctly returns an array in the form of {1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four"}
            $el.empty(); // remove existing options
            $.each(newOptions, function(key,value) {
                $el.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

If I now call: `$('#selectbox').val();` I get undefined and I'm not sure why? To make matters more confusing, if I disable *#selectbox* (using a toggle switch that adds `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` to *#selectbox*, then try `$('#selectbox').val();` I get the expected val of 1, 2, 3, etc.

How can I get this value without disabling the box, or what have I overlooked?

---

**Edit:**

I've been asked where my `$('#selectbox').val();` call is. It's not any more involved than I mentioned above, but to be thorough, it's called from a submit button in the same div as the select element as follows:

```
$("#submitbutton").on('click', function() {
    var selectBoxVal = $('#selectbox').val();
    console.log('value is: ' + selectBoxVal);
    return false;
});
```

My only idea so far is that it may be a dom issue? I say that ignorantly as my knowledge doesn't quite know the full ins and outs but I've seen issues where elements are altered live by javascript and not retrieved correctly by later javascript calls - whereas they work fine if the elements being retrieved existed when the page loaded.

I don't assign a selected property to any of the options but I don't believe this should cause *undefined* to be returned. For example, if I disable the select box, the value is returned correctly from the same query (as mentioned above) yet it still doesn't have a selected property added manually. I digress, but is it required to add a selected property when creating a series of options in javascript? Which option is initially presented as selected is irrelevant to me from a usage point of view but I'd be happy to follow best procedures. I assumed that the browser interpreted the displayed option as selected if none were marked as such.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the value of the select in the `success` callback, or setting one of the `option`s' `selected` properties...

Comment: Why you expect `1, 2, 3`??!!

Comment: Where is your $('#selectbox').val(); call? Probably you are calling it before appending the options.

Comment: If your ajax request return the response you shown in the OP so the result  of `$("#selectbox").val()` should be `1` check https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/369/

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki, that example returns 1 for me no matter what option I choose (Safari 10.0.03). I expect 1, 2, or 3 because they're some of the example values I gave the array in the example I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "value" of the select will be the `<option>` that has the attribute "selected" within that selectbox.  Otherwise, there is no indicated value for that input.

Comment: How that answer the question/Solve the issue?

Comment: Part of the question was: "What have I overlooked?"  I believe this is an aspect of the select element that the OP may have overlooked.

Comment: The select will take the first option as selected if there no one by default, so in this case the `$("#selectbox").val()` should return `1` and not `undefined`.

Comment: I had (perhaps wrongly) believed that if an option doesn't have a property of selected added by javascript, that the current option displayed by the select box in the browser is inherently the selected one. Nevertheless, if I add a disabled option to the select box, it returns the value of the option, but not if it's enabled, where it returns undefined. I can't make sense of this.